# Unload SQL Query result to a variable instead of a file on a shell script

Tags: mysql, database, bash, shell

While getting information from a MySQL database from a shell script I normally have to unload the result to a file to gather all output in a line:

```
mysql -uroot -p'password' dbname<<EOFMYSQL
SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table1
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file.txt'
EOFMYSQL
```

Output:

```
val1_1|val2_1
val1_2|val2_2
...
```

Instead of multiple lines when I dump the output to a variable without `INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file.txt'`:

```
col1 val1_1
col2 val2_1
col1 val1_2
...
```

I would like to know if there is a way not to use files while getting the first format output into a variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `UNLOAD` is not MySQL syntax. Are you using MySQL or Informix?

Comment: So you're asking how to get `SELECT` to print CSV-style output to standard output, not only when it's unloading to a file?

Comment: Yeah i corrected the question, sorry. I used mysql as an example as I thought it would be more popular

Comment: But if you're really using Informix, how would a MySQL solution help?

Comment: yes, get a csv output to a variable without intermediary file. I want to know for both, I just used the wrong syntax

Comment: I don't think there's a way in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I just have to use /dev/stdout as the output file.
Thanks all